# Throwing exceptions on AWS Lambda with Node12.x in Axios catch handlers

Tags: node.js, exception, aws-lambda, axios

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how I can make this function work. I think it stems from me not really understanding 100% how to handle promises, but I've read all the tutorials I can find and I still don't see how I can do this.

The following is a function, which calls an endpoint on an API. When it's successful, it'll return a token for use in future requests. When it fails, I want to throw an exception and completely stop the execution.

I've heard that when throwing in a catch handler like this, then you're thrown exception is handled by a hidden try/catch and this passes to the next catch handler. But this is effectively meaning my exception gets black-holed. Which I've heard is a thing and I've read other questions on this website about that.

The actual example isn't this trivial. But the effective code is still the same, a try/catch wrapped around all the code in question. But any exceptions never land in the right place. Then lambda fails with the exception in question. But it's not handled by the code that I wrote, so the response is wrong. I need to handle the code and output a different reply based on what exception is being thrown. So I change it around, fix up the data, add other related information and return that. But since I'm never landing in the right place. I can never do that.

How could I alter this function, so that it correctly lands in the exception handler I've given? Thanks for your help

```
    let getToken = async () => {
        let transport = axios.create({ baseURL, headers: passwordHeaders });

        return transport.post('/authorization/login')
            .then(response => {
                let accessToken = _.get(response, 'data.access_token', null);
                if(accessToken !== null){
                    let base64 = Buffer.from(accessToken, 'base64');
                    let token = base64.toString('ascii');

                    return token.split(";").shift().split(":").pop();
                }

                throw new LoginError(response.statusText, response.status));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if(_.get(error, 'response.status', 'null') === 403){
                    throw new UnauthorizedError(error.response.statusText);
                }

                throw error;
            });
    }

    try{
        let token = await getToken();
    }catch(error){
        console.log("this exception should land here");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using async/await and `.then()` together ?

Comment: The problem starts with the mix of `async` and `then` style syntax.

`async` keyword makes a function a promise. So your getToken function is returning a promise wrapped in a promise. You could remove the `async` keyword or make actually use of the `async` keyword by using `await`

Comment: Yeah see, I understand coding, but I just don't get promises. I use the `.then()` because axios works like this, you use the `.then()` in order to handle the result from the API call. I thought that If I returned the result, it was a promise? But clearly, I've just not understood how to put this together. Let me try these solutions and see whether it works

Comment: That hasn't actually changed the result. I removed the async from the function. The result is that the catch still doesn't catch what is thrown from the `.catch()` handler. The problem I think is still that the exception is still black-holed by the `.catch()` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the problems the main problem is the mix of `then` style and `async`/`await`. If we lean into the `async` approach we could do the following:

```js
let getToken = async () => {
  let transport = axios.create({ baseURL });

  try {
    const response = await transport.post("/authorization/login");

    let accessToken = _.get(response, "data.access_token", null);
    if (accessToken !== null) {
      let base64 = Buffer.from(accessToken, "base64");
      let token = base64.toString("ascii");

      return token.split(";").shift().split(":").pop();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};

try {
  let token = await getToken();
} catch (error) {
  console.log("this exception should land here");
}
```

As `getToken` is an asynchronous function it returns a `Promise`, returning within this function equals to using `Promise.resolve` and throwing equals to `Promise.reject`. In my case the catch block of `getToken` does not do anything and getToken gets called from within a `try / catch`. We might want to delegate error handling to the outer try catch by removing the inner one.

Comment: Finally got this working, I had to do more work at each level of the code to get this to fully work through the app. But now I'm getting the response I need, thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad you got it running. Have a great day :)